# Utilizar div de HTML e armazená-la como variável

Tags: php, html, div

Tenho uma página web lúdica, na qual existem 2 divs, e em uma página PHP, gostaria de dar um random nelas, a parte do `array rand` eu já sei como fazer, o problema está na hora de pegar as divs do HTML e mandá-las para o PHP, eis o que tenho até agora:

```
<html>
<div id="1">bla bla bla</div>
<div id="2">bla bla bla bla bla</div>
</html>
```

e agora, a parte em PHP:

```
<?php

$var1="div 1 iria aqui";
$var2="div 2 iria aqui";

$random = array('$var1','$var2');

echo $random[array_rand($random)];
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, faça o [tour] e leia o [ask]

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga, o que a torna incompreensível. É melhor editá-la, fornecendo mais informações. Sugiro especificar melhor que tipo de tratamento e modelo que você quer.

Comment: Queres `<div id="1">bla bla bla</div>` na variável ou  `bla bla bla`?

Comment: Use javascript para pegar o conteudo da div e envie ele por ajax para o php.

Comment: @JorgeB. quero pegar a div inteira.

Comment: @rray você poderia postar um exemplo aqui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o javascript para pegar o id da div e envie por ajax. Esse exemplo usa jquery, não esqueça de adicionar ele no seu teste/projeto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#web").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method : "post",
            url : "response.php",
            //data, são informados os campos enviados para o php
            data: {'div1': $("#1").prop('outerHTML'), 'div2' : $("#2").prop('outerHTML'))}
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="1">frase 1</div>
   <div id="2">frase 2</div>
   <input type="button" id="web" name="web" value="teste" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ele não quer só o conteúdo...

Comment: @JorgeB. vou editar então, valeu o aviso :)

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar jQuery para isso:

```
$.post('exemplo.php', {var1: document.getElementById('1').outerHTML});
```

No PHP:

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
```